# Import Excel Sheet Using LinqToExcel and not getting data propare read from excel to database in Asp.net Mvc c#?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, model-view-controller, linq-to-excel

I am trying to import excel data using `LinqToExcel` in my asp.net mvc project. I am importing an Excel that has 2 columns, 1 is `Itemcode` and other is `Quantity`. 
It has 1 row.
Quantity column has value 0.8. When the Excel is uploaded, the value changes from "0.8" to "0". I want to have a value of 0.8.

This is my code:

```
 List<Product> Excelpro = new List<Product>();
            var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(spath);
            var Epro = from a in excelFile.Worksheet<Product>(sheetName) select a;

            var firstRow = excelFile.Worksheet().ToList();
             Excelpro = Epro.ToList();
```

This is my class:

```
public class Product
{
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public Decimal Quantity { get; set; }
 }
```

This is my excel:

```
ItemCode    Quantity
 HJGH       0.8
```

I don't know what is the issue. please if any one has any idea about this issue then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle/reading an Xl sheet is use **EPPlus**. you can read complete Xl-sheet in form of DataSet or DataTable and you can maintain what ever datatypes you want while converting.

Link :[Read/Write/Carete Xl-sheet by EPPlus](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/680421/Create-Read-Edit-Advance-Excel-Report-in).

just go through that while importing xl-just keep the column formats as text, get into dataset or DataTable and use how ever you want.